# I want to set cookie field and also character set to handle chinese character using curl command

Tags: python, unix, curl, utf-8

I am using `curl -b token url` to generate the json but I am not able to handle Chinese characters. How to add character set to utf-8 to handle Chinese characters?

Comment: [HTTP Headers - Accept-Charset](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Accept-Charset)

Comment: I am redirecting the output of curl command(which is json) to a txt file, then I am parsing the json using python 2.6 version, I am able to parse everything but for chinese characters it is showing like \xe8\xaf\xb7\xe8\xbe and so on in the txt file after parsing. So the issue is I am not able to parse the chinese character from json. I tried using encode, decode utf-8 function and whatever is given in google but it didn't worked. Any suggestions would be highly appreciated.